# AngularJs ui-router not working in Spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular-ui-router

I am using the UI-router library with Spring Boot and Spring Security.
When I try to access a route I have defined, nothing happens, I don't even get an error in the console.

Here is my app.js file

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
//
// For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
//
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('default', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "partials/firstpage.html"
    })

.state('register', {
    url: "/register",
    templateUrl: "partials/register.html"
})

.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "partials/login.html"
})
```

});

The index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"> </script>

<script src="app.js"> </script>
<script src="controllers/navbar.controller.js"> </script>

</head>

<body>
<div ui-view> </div>

</body>
```

The WebSecurityConfiguration class:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/",
                    "/*.html",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js",
                    "/**/**/*.css",
                    "/**/**/*.js",
                    "/**/**/*.html",
                    "/**/**/**/*.css",
                    "/**/**/**/*.js",
                    "/**/**/**/*.html",
                    "/**/**/**/**/*.css",
                    "/**/**/**/**/*.js"          
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    // Custom JWT based authentication
    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

And here is my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qn7o.png)

Is there anything that I should add to my code to configure the ui-router library for Spring boot?

Comment: <html lang="en" ng-app="app">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code doesn't have an `ng-app` directive. So basically your angular app is not getting initalized